# Restore Mongodb connection after failure

Tags: java, mongodb, networking

We have a large MongoDB collection with ~10 millions of documents and we need to process them in some way and export our data into files.

To do so we need to read every record from the collection via cursor.
MongoDB runs inside docker swarm mode so it has some network instability and sometimes we face `Socket Exception: Connection reset`.

`WARN org.mongodb.driver.connection - Got socket exception on connection
 to localhost:27017. All connections to localhost:27017 will be closed.`

It occurs at random time (sometimes it doesn't appear at all) and MongoDB Java driver immediately closes the connection and stops processing.
But when I use Nodejs mongodb driver it works fine and doesn't fail at all.

Maybe I'm missing some options or something?

We're using MongoDB 3.4 and mongodb-driver-async 3.4 from maven.